# Binance websocket stream no response

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to stream ethusdt from binance but I don't get any response below is my code:

```py
import websocket

SOCKET = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ethusdt@kline_1m"


def on_open(ws):
    print('Opened Connection')


def on_close(ws):
    print('Closed Connection')


def on_message(ws, message):
    print('Received Message')


ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```